# Softlayer Server_ID

Tags: python-2.7, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to implement the following:

```
import SoftLayer.API
username = 'set me!'
apiKey = 'set me too!'
serverId = 1234       
client = SoftLayer.API.Client('SoftLayer_Hardware_Server', serverId, username, apiKey)
```

Here, I don't really know how to retrieve the **serverId**. How could I know my server ID for a specific server. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SoftLayer_Account::getHardware](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware) retrieves information about your hardware objects, in which you can find the serverIds from your servers.

Try this python script:

```
"""
This script retrieves an account's associated hardware objects

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer.API

# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer username and api key
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# Creates a new connection to the API service.
client = SoftLayer.API.Client(username=API_USERNAME,api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    hardwareObjects = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getHardware()
    pp(hardwareObjects)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to get hardware objects faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

This script will return the information from your servers, in which the **"id"** property  refers to serverId from the server that you need.

However, if you wish to retrieve the information for an specific server, it can be done using [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters), here an example:

```
"""
This script retrieves a hardware information for an specific hardware object.
It is only necessary to specify the hostname from the server.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer.API

# For nice debug output:
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Your SoftLayer username and api key
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
# Define the hostname from the hardware object
hostname = 'hostnametest'

# Declare an object filter to get an specific hardware object
filterHardware = {
    'hardware': {
        'hostname': {
            'operation': hostname
        }
    }
}

# Creates a new connection to the API service.
client = SoftLayer.API.Client(username=API_USERNAME,api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    hardwareObjects = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getHardware(filter=filterHardware)
    pp(hardwareObjects)

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        pp('Unable to get the hardware object faultCode=%s, faultString=%s'
            % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

You need to specify the "hostname" from your server. The **"id"** in the response refers to serverId.

**Some references:**

- [Using Initialization Parameters in the SoftLayer
  API](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/using-initialization-parameters-softlayer-api)
- [SoftLayer Python](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Python)
- [Going Further with the SoftLayer API Python Client - Part 1](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-1)